# Computer suspends monitor after 5 minutes, then deactivates it... I don't want this to happen

Tags: 16.04

System Information:

```
Model: Acer Veriton VN282G-UD5253W
Processor: Intel Atom D525 1.80GHz
Chipset: Intel NM10
Memory: 4GB DDR3
Hard Drive: 500GB
Graphics: NVIDIA ION GPU - GT218
OS: Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS, 64bit
Browser: Google Chrome-Version 51.0.2704.84, 64bit
```

(This is my home theater PC, hooked to a 50" HDTV via HDMI @ 720p)

This computer has a new install of Ubuntu 16.04, & upgrade all software via Synaptic & Software Updater.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

My question is this: when I leave my computer up, as when I play music, it plays for about 5 minutes, then shuts down the monitor, which in this case is my TV.

The PC is attached to the TV via a single HDMI cable, and the sound runs from the TV via RCA cables to my stereo, which is a JVC boom box. When the monitor (TV) is shut down, the music stops, because it is routed through the TV.

A simple tap of the space bar brings it back up, still playing my music, for another 5 minutes, when it repeats the suspension again.

I do not have any settings set to suspend, nor deactivate the monitor. Not in power settings, either.

Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not in Power Settings. You need to look under `System Settings > Brightness & Lock`, and select your preferred screen timeout under `Turn screen off when inactive for:`